# ipython can't load a module which python does

Tags: macos, python-2.7, ipython

I have recently updated to OSX El Capitain upgrading an exhisting working osx installation. Now I have a module, installed via pip on an anaconda distribution which is now broken. Or better the module can be correctly imported from python

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:29:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import MDSplus as mds
```

whereas it does not load on ipython, claiming not to finding a library.

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:29:08) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX

In [1]: import MDSplus as mds
Error importing MDSplus package: Error finding library: MdsShr
```

The library is correctly installed, it is listed in /etc/profile, it is located in /usr/local (so there should not be a problem with the new security system of OSX el Captain) and the python interpreted which is called via python or ipython is the same (Anaconda 2.3.0).
How can I diagnose which is the problem?

EDIT:
the solution proposed in https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/PEuOKEM5fdc does not worked for me. It does not seem to be an environment problem and the command

```
echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

points to the correct path

EDIT:

```
which -a ipython
ipython is /Users/vianello/anaconda/bin/ipython
which -a python 
python is /Users/vianello/anaconda/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python

>>> import sys
>>> for x in sys.path: print x
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhht-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MitDevices-0.3-py2.7.egg
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MDSplus-alpha_7.0.157-py2.7.egg
>>>//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MDSplus-alpha_7.0.147-py2.7.egg/MDSplus
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python27.zip
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lmfit-0.8.3-py2.7.egg
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.3.2-py2.7.egg
>>>/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg
```

in iPython the same give the results

```
/Users/vianello/anaconda/bin
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhht-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MitDevices-0.3-py2.7.egg
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MDSplus-alpha_7.0.157-py2.7.egg
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python27.zip
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lmfit-0.8.3-py2.7.egg
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.3.2-py2.7.egg
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa
/Users/vianello/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions
/Users/vianello/.ipython
```

Thus the MDSplus-alpha_7.0.157-py2.7.egg can be seen both from python and ipython

Comment: Yes I did and the solution proposed did not solved the problem, i.e. adding to the PYTHONPATH did not solve the issue

Comment: You are right, I've edited the question sorry

Comment: Are you running ipython from a virtualenv?

Comment: No, I don't actually

Comment: please add the output of `which -a ipython` and `which -a python` to your question.

Comment: I added the information to the original question

Comment: `import sys` and  `sys.path`    from both pythons and see if the module's path is available in both.

Comment: I am also missing `MdsShr` when trying to set up MDSplus on a fresh install of Fedora 25.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you are running afoul of the new Apple System Integrity Protection. iPython is launched using a shell script that loads via `/bin/bash`. That will result in your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable being stripped when python launches. You can check this by importing `os` and then attempting to print the contents of `os.environ["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"]`. If that print throws an exception then you know what the problem is.

A simple fix that works for me is to edit the first line of the `ipython` script so that the `#!` calls your python binary directly rather than going via bash. This is not a long term solution as it will have to be redone each time ipython is updated until upstream changes (to be fair I'm not sure why bash is involved).

I have written a report on python and library paths at http://dmtn-001.lsst.io